# C# arr.contains() using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, contains

Code example

```
string[] black_list = { "Music", "Voice", "Animal" };

for (byte i = 0; i < black_list.Length; i++)
{
    //string pattern = $@"^{Convert.ToString(black_list[i])}$";
    arr = arr.Where(line => !line.Contains(Convert.ToString(black_list[i])).ToArray();
}
```

It removes any match from the "black_list" array from the "arr" array. But not a complete match. For example, if one of the strings in the arr array is "Music video" - one string, then this string will also be deleted. I need to delete strictly "Music" but not "Music video". In a regex it should be something like this ^black_list[i]$ right? ^ - start of line. $ - end of line. But I don't know how to make .Contains and Regex friends.

Comment: Seems like you want `line == black_list[i]`?

Comment: can you tell more example or say you pattern?(if arry )
Only those that start with that list are ok. Can you give some explanations?

Comment: start of line "Music" end of line. Is it clear now?

Comment: Can't you use the `==` operator?

Comment: Also you don't need to use `Converate.ToString` on something that is already a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be use Regex( first or end in the list), you can use this code

```
arr = arr.Where(r => 
!black_list.Any(d => 
Regex.Match(r, d + @"$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success 
|| Regex.Match(r, @"^" + d , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)).ToArray();
```

If you want it to be the first or end in the list, use this code

```
arr = arr.Where(r => 
!black_list.Any(d => 
r.ToLower().StartsWith(d.ToLower()) || r.ToLower().EndsWith(d.ToLower()))

).ToArray();
```

If you want it to be equal the list, use this code

```
arr = arr.Where(r => !black_list.Any(d =>
 r.ToLower().Equals(d.ToLower()))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your first code produces exactly the same result as mine.

Comment: I ran your example and this is the result. Imagine that I have an array of 4 strings? "The Music, Music, Music Video, The Music Video". And the second array is a black list with only one "Music" string. My code removes all rows. Your code removes all lines except "The Music Video", since there are only 3 words and "Music" in the center. And I want to achieve the result that only one line would be erased - "Music"

Comment: I need from an array `string[] arr = { "The Music, Music, Music Video, The Music Video" };` make an array `string[] arr = { "The Music, Music Video, The Music Video" };` I need to remove only the complete match.

Comment: You said if this is the first and last. If you want it to be exactly equal, you must use the equal

Comment: I said that I need to delete the line - quote "start of line "Music" end of line"

Comment: I understood something else.
 I edited the code according to your comment (last part, for equal).

Answer (score 1):

System.Linq is amazing. In my case, you can do without a regular expression

```
string[] black_list = { "Music", "Voice", "Animal" };    
arr = arr.Except(black_list).ToArray();
```